# Replace value in array with condition

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, numpy

I have this simplified program to replace values in array which fulfill the conditions:

```
formula1=2*2
formula2=5*2
formula3=4*4

array = np.random.rand(2,4,10)
for n,i in enumerate(array):
    if i>0.5: #find value in array with this condition
        formula = formula1
        array[n] = array[n]*formula #replace the found value with this value
    elif i <0.1:
        formula = formula2
        array[n] = array[n]*formula
    else:
        formula = formula3
        array[n] = array[n]*formula
print array
```

It resulted in error message:'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you add the complete traceback?

Comment: @syntonym if i<0.5:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: In your for loop, `i` is an array. How would you determine if an array is lesser than a given value? `any()` checks if any of the elements in the array is lesser than the given value and `all()` checks if all the elements are

Comment: @SvbZ3r0 isn't any() or all() used to find boolean value of True and False only?

Comment: Not necessarily. Try `np.any(array<0.5)` to see if any of the values in `array` are lesser than 0.5

Comment: It's answered. Thank you for your advices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enumerate an array, you can use `np.ndenumerate` ([documentation here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html)):

```
for n, i in np.ndenumerate(array):
    ...
```